# Delta in Epsilon delta definition of limit

Tags: limits

We know delta in epsilon delta definition of limit depends upon epsilon.
Can delta in epsilon delta definition of limits depend upon x also?

Comment: The value of $\delta$ depends on the value of $x$ and $\epsilon.$

Comment: Yes, it depends on $x$ in general.

Comment: When it does not depend on $x$, it leads to the notion of *uniform* continuity, convergence, &c.

Comment: When it does not depend on $x$, we say that the convergence is *uniform*. This is an important property. [Crossed with Bernard]

Comment: Yes, but it can't be a function of $x$ only $\epsilon$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and it often does!

For example, let's say that $f$ is a real-valued function on some subset $E$ of the real line. We say that $f$ is *continuous* if for every $\epsilon>0$ and every $x\in E,$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that, whenever $y\in E$ and $|x-y|<\delta,$ we have $\bigl|f(x)-f(y)\bigr|<\epsilon.$ This $\delta,$ though, may be different for different $x,$ even when $\epsilon$ is the same. For instance, consider $f(x)=\frac1x$ and $E=\{x\in\Bbb R:x\ne 0\}.$ We can show that $f$ is continuous, but we'll need to choose smaller $\delta$-values as $x$ gets closer to $0,$ since $f$ is changing so rapidly there.

Now, we say that $f$ is *uniformly continuous* if for every $\epsilon>0,$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that, whenever $x,y\in E$ and $|x-y|<\delta,$ we have $\bigl|f(x)-f(y)\bigr|<\epsilon.$ In this case, the $\delta$ does *not* depend on $x.$ Bringing it back to the function $f(x)=\frac1x,$ but with $E=[1,\infty),$ instead, it turns out that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $E$! Since $f$ changes less and less quickly the farther $x$ gets from $0,$ all we need to do is find a $\delta$ that works when $x=1,$ and it will work for all other $x\in E,$ as well!